# Attaching JSON web token to the http requests

Tags: node.js

I have a token named userToken, it's in localstorage. I need to attach this token to http requests (get/post) since I check whether a user is logged in or not using this token.

I implemented it for jQuery Ajax post requests, now I can work with them, but I have no idea how to attach it to **all http requests** (for instance, a simple get request), with or without ajax.

Here's what I've done so far:

Jade

```
#click Click here
```

script.js (Client Side)

```
var _token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'token' : _token }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#click').click(function () {
        $.post("/testurl2", {}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

NodeJS

```
app.get('/testurl1', function(req,res) {
    var myPreciousToken = req.headers.token;
    console.log(myPreciousToken); // it doesn't work.
});

app.post('/testurl2', function(req,res) {
    var myPreciousToken = req.headers.token;
    console.log(myPreciousToken); // it works
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `ajaxSetup` to

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    //headers: { 'token' : _token },
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('token', _token );
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, still get undefined. I edited my question a little bit. Thank you.